# Function 'CudnnConvolutionBackward' returned nan values in its 1th output

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train this simple convolutional model:

```
class Modello1(nn.Module):

#struttura del modello
def __init__(self, in_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3, hidden_size4, hidden_size5, out_size):
    
    super().__init__()
    
    kernel_size = 3 #3
    stride = 3 #2 
    padding = 3 #3
    
    
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_size, hidden_size1, kernel_size, stride, padding)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size, padding = 1, stride = 3)
    
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(hidden_size1, hidden_size2, kernel_size, stride, padding)

    self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(hidden_size2, hidden_size3, kernel_size, stride, padding)

    # IMPORTANTE, qui aggiungere un livello di flattening (flatten qualcosa)?

    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size3, hidden_size4)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size4, hidden_size5)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size5, out_size)
    
#i dati attraversano il modello   
def forward(self, input_data): 
    
    input_data = torch.reshape(input_data, (input_data.shape[0],input_data.shape[1],1)) 
    input_data = input_data.float()
    
    out = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(input_data))) #70 neuroni       
    out = torch.reshape(out, (out.shape[0],out.shape[1],1))  

    out = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(out))) #33 neuroni  
    out = torch.reshape(out, (out.shape[0],out.shape[1],1)) 
    
    out = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(out))) #33 neuroni  
    out = torch.reshape(out, (out.shape[0],out.shape[1]))
    
    out = F.relu(self.linear1(out))    
    out = F.relu(self.linear2(out))
    out = self.linear3(out)
    return out
    
#calcolo loss e accuratezza batch
def validation_step(self, batch):
    
    input_data, targets = batch 
    out = self(input_data) 
    targets = targets.view(targets.shape[0])
    targets = targets.long()
    loss = criterion(out, targets)
    acc = accuracy(out,targets)
    
    return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}


#loss e accuratezza di ciascuna epoca
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    #print(outputs)
    batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
    epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   #media tra le losses di ogni batch
    batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
    batch_accs = torch.tensor(batch_accs)
    epoch_acc = torch.mean(batch_accs) 

    return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc}
```

I use torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True) function to check anomalies in loss.backward() function and as soon as I start the training process I obtain this error: Function 'CudnnConvolutionBackward' returned nan values in its 1th output. Does anyone have any idea why it appens?

Here is the rest of the code:

## accuracy function

```
def accuracy(outputs, targets):
dim = targets.shape[0]
preds = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(dim).fill_(0)
_, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    
i = 0
j = 0

targets = targets.long()
for x in preds:
    
    if(x == targets[i]):
        j+=1
        
    i+=1

return (j / i) * 100
```

## Criterion and optimizer

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

## Evaluation and fit function

```
def evaluate(model, val_loader):
outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit(epochs, model, train_loader, val_loader):

history = [] #stores loss e accuracy for each epoch

for epoch in range(epochs): 
    since = time.time()

    running_loss = 0.0
    
    for batch in train_loader:
        
        inputs, targets = batch

        optimizer.zero_grad() 

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        targets = targets.view(targets.shape[0])
        targets = targets.long()
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step() 
  
    #validation phase       
    result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
    history.append(result)

    running_loss += loss.item()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since

    print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}%".format(epoch, result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('-' * 10)

    running_loss = 0.0

return history
```

## Training

```
model = Modello1(input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3, hidden_size4, hidden_size5, out_size)
history = fit(10, model, train_loader, val_loader)
```

Comment: Please give minimal reproducible code

Comment: @root163 I've just updated my question

Comment: Can you run it in inference mode without an error? If so, do the outputs fall within a normal range and contain no `nan` values?

Comment: Does this error arise on the first backwards pass you call? Another possible lead is that `ReLU` is non-differentiable at input = 0. To wit, if you fail to initialize your model parameters with random non-zero values, all weights will be equal to 0 and your gradient will be undefined (`nan`). You can initialize with `nn.init`

Comment: Where is Modello1 defined??

Comment: @root163 Sorry, I've updated the question again with the definition ad Modello1

Comment: @DerekG Thanks for your hints. I've checked the gradient and they are not nan, but I've found out that some of the inputs of the first convolutional layer are nan instead (even if I thought I deleted them during the preprocessing).  Besides, now the error has changed turning into RuntimeError: Function 'LogSoftmaxBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output. Do you think that the problem can be the nan inputs?